Effect of starting temperature on thermistor still air time constant measurement
The still air time thermal time constant is stated in datasheets and is understood to be the time it takes for the sensor to cool to 63.2% of the difference between itself and the ambient temperature. It is normally measured by self-heating the thermistor, waiting until it is thermodynamically stable and then disconnecting the power and measuring how long this takes.
I'm calculating how long the time constant should be expected to be for a given thermistor and have found that the time constant appears to be much shorter when the starting temperature is higher, but this contradicts literature I have read that says the starting temperature doesn't matter, since it is a percentage change that is measured.
For a vertical cylinder with aspect ratio 2, according to [1], the Nusselt number is:
Nu = -0.3903 + 0.5399Ra^0.25 + 0.637(Length/Diameter)
where the Rayleigh number is:
Ra = Pr·g·β·(T_surface - T_ambient)·L^3 / ν^2
(where Pr is the Prandtl number, g is gravity, β is 1/T_ambient for an ideal gas, L is length and ν is kinematic viscosity)
For 25°C ambient temperature, evaluating Nu at 100°C gives Nu = 2.9, whilst at 35°C it is 2.1.
The heat transfer coefficient, h = Nu·k/L. Since the time constant, τ = C / (h·A) and both the heat capacity (C) and surface area (A) remain constant, this implies that the still air time constant varies greatly depending upon the object's temperature.
Is this correct? (And if not, why not?)
Thanks.
[1] Laminar Natural Convection From Isothermal Vertical Cylinders- Revisting a Classical Subject 2013 JC Day et al [https://doi.org/10.1115/1.4007421]

Broadly, the time constant you're describing is temperature independent if the material and geometric properties are constant along with the convection coefficient $h$ that describes linear convective heat loss $hA(T-T_\mathrm{ambient})$. Your sources that assume a single time constant are also implicitly assuming that these conditions are satisfied.
The time constant doesn't vary much if these parameters are minimally dependent on the temperature.
The time constant can alternatively be considered the time emerging from discretization of the relevant transient heat equation. For the lumped-component model, for example, an energy balance gives
$$C\frac{dT}{dt}+hA(T-T_\mathrm{ambient})=0$$
with heat capacity $C$, uniform temperature $T$, time $t$, convection coefficient $h$, surface area $A$, and ambient temperature $T_\mathrm{ambient}$. Substitution of $\Delta T=T-T_\mathrm{ambient}$ and discretization gives
$$C\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta t}\sim -hA\Delta T;$$
$$|\Delta t|\sim\frac{C}{hA},$$
with "$\sim$" indicating a scaling relation—an order-of-magnitude estimate, say. The change you're describing corresponds to increase of about 28%, which is less than an order of magnitude off but may still be too much for your purposes to consider the time constant to be essentially unchanged. In other words, over a temperature range of 35°C to 100°C, estimates of the time constant really need to include the starting and ending temperatures for reference, since the Nusselt number changes enough that the constant can't really be considered "constant." Put another way, replacing $h$ with temperature-dependent $h(t)$ makes the partial differential equation above nonlinear, precluding a simple exponential solution that contains a single time constant.
